# Setting initial value for computed property with vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[image]

I'm trying out vuejs by following along with the laracasts series of webcasts on this. In https://laracasts.com/series/learning-vue-step-by-step/episodes/6, Jeffery Way has put the code in the http://jsfiddle.net/d4f27e5p/ .

The initial setting is shown in the screenshot, before any plan is selected. I would like to set a default value in the button of "please select " (instead of "Downgrade") The button code is:

```
<span v-else>
        <button @click="setActivePlan">
            {{ isUpgrade ? 'Upgrade' : 'Downgrade' }}
        </button>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about adding a computed property for the button text that includes the additional logic? Something like this:

```
buttonText: function() {
  if(!this.active.name)
    return "Please Select";

  return this.isUpgrade ? 'Upgrade' : 'Downgrade';
}
```

Then the button would use this:

```
<span v-else>
    <button @click="setActivePlan">
        {{ buttonText }}
    </button>
</span>
```

Here's an updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vk4m6xxs/1/).

Comment: Thank you Peter, that works! I tried something similar at http://jsfiddle.net/d4f27e5p/44/ . Unfortunately its not working, Any idea why?

Comment: You were close. Here's an updated fiddle that fixes the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/d4f27e5p/45/. You had changed `isUpgrade` to return the button text but you hadn't updated the template. I just changed the button content to {{ isUpgrade }}.